# Domain Name forwarding in Azure DNS service

Tags: powershell, azure, dns

I am using Azure DNS for a website that I have migrated to hubspot. I have created a CNAME record from www.mydomain.com to the hubspot hosted website. As described in [this document](http://knowledge.hubspot.com/articles/kcs_article/cos-general/how-to-go-live-with-hubspot-using-godaddy)

I am looking to also redirect the Apex domain mydomain.com to the hubspot hosted website. However I do not have a hubspot IP Address only a CNAME endpoint. How can I redirect mydomain.com to the hubspot domain without an IP Address.

Comment: This is tricky. You may additionally need to configure the A record for the domain name. When you configure custom domain it provides instructions to configure A record. Or additionally you can configure awverify.www.domain.com record along with awverify.domain.com

Comment: Kiran I hope you don't mind but I have rewritten your question to make it a little clearer what you are asking. If you disagree with the edit feel free to roll it back.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is an issue with the [rules of DNS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034), which forbid a CNAME record where another record exists. The naked address (or Apex) example.com already has two records (the SOA and NS) so a CNAME is not allowed.

> If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be
> present; this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its aliases
> cannot be different.  This rule also insures that a cached CNAME can be
> used without checking with an authoritative server for other RR types.

In order to create an Apex record, i.e. example.com you need to use an A record, which means it needs to point to the IP of your Azure website. Once you have that you can then create a CNAME from www to example.com. (this is the supported method - your IP Address for Azure websites is static)

the command you are looking for, would be something like

```
$rs = New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet -Name "@" -RecordType A `
       -ZoneName example.com -ResourceGroupName $RG `
       -Ttl $ttl -Force -Overwrite
Add-AzureRmDnsRecordConfig -RecordSet $rs -Ipv4Address $IPAddress
Set-AzureRmDnsRecordSet -RecordSet $rs -Overwrite
```

then

```
$rs = New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet -Name "www" -RecordType "CNAME" `
      -ZoneName "something.com" -ResourceGroupName "DNSRecords" `
      -Ttl 60 -Overwrite -Force
Add-AzureRmDnsRecordConfig -RecordSet $rs -Cname "example.com"
Set-AzureRmDnsRecordSet -RecordSet $rs -Overwrite
```

If you don't have an IP address to point your apex A record to then the only solution you have is to use an IP address that will provide HTTP redirect for you.

The simplest way I can think of doing this would be to create a small Azure Web App and use that IP Address to send a [HTTP status 301 Moved Permanently](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.2) header. This would place negligible load on the server because it wouldn't actually be serving any pages.

An alternative would be switching to a DNS provider that does provide apex CNAME (or at least a workaround to provide similar functionality)

There are also some HTTP redirect services (both free and paid) at the end of a [search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=apex+http+redirect+service) (However I've never used any of these so I can't comment on the quality!)

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your answer. I have already done with the steps you answered. these steps can be used for adding new records or updating existing records. but my Question is how to forward a domain to www where i have pointed CNAME already. Thanks

Comment: @Kiran I don't entirely understand what you are trying to do. do you want web.example.com pointing to the existing cname www.example.com? if not, can you give an example (.com ;) )

Comment: ok let me explain once again. i have migrated my site to hubspot which provides me a hostname (suppose mydomain.hubspot,net). now i can set this hostname as CNAME record to www.mydomain,com. and its working fine. any user hitting www.mydomain.com is redirecting to correct address (i.e. my website on hubspot). now consider a scenario when user is accessing site only with naked domain name like mydomain.com. as of now i have not pointed my domain name to any A record. thats what i want to do. i dont have any IP address to point my domain name on hubspot.

Comment: @Kiran Ok, I understand, I will modify the answer to include that

Comment: Hello Michael, I did the same thing i redirected it via different machine, so now when user access mydomain.com he/she gets redirected to www.mydomain.com where he/she can see my site working fine. Thanks a lot for all your help.